# Disable line breaks after loops without body

Tags: eclipse

Consider a Java while-loop without a body, for example this:

```
while (map.values().remove(value));
```

When formatting it (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + F), Eclipse breaks the line before the semicolon and indents it:

```
while (map.values().remove(value))
  ;
```

**How can I configure the formatter to not add these line breaks?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that by setting this semicolon to a new line, you may avoid unintended endless loops and a long search to find them.

However, in Eclipse all code formatting properties are 1) in the project properties and 2) in the Eclipse properties. The project properties inherit from the Eclipse properties.

So if you open the project properties, type "format" in the search field. It will show you a "Formatter" menu item, that may depend on the current language (at least in Java it is called "Formatter"). Then, in this example, allow the project-specific settings, and then click edit. You will see a flood of possible details you can decide.

See here:

[image]

Then, in the tab "New Lines", uncheck the checkbox "Put empty statement on new line", in the section "Empty statements".

Often you have to try and search a bit because there are really many options. The part at right shows you a preview of the code formatting.

Comment: I already knew of that window, but I cannot seem to find an option that would disable the line break after loops without bodies.

Comment: I've added my findings to the answer. See again.